# sort list of lists by specific index of inner list

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

I am trying perform some operation on a file and convert its lines to list. However the integer values are also taken as string

```
l1 = [['test', 'hello', '60,'], ['why', 'to', '500,'], ['my', 'choice', '20,']]
```

because of this I am unable to sort the list of list based on these integer values.

Is there a way I can convert all these `list[2]` values into integer and sort the outer list based on that?  Or any other way via which I can sort this list using integers in above list.

Intended result is, output of sorted list should show as:

```
[['my', 'choice', '20,'], ['test', 'hello', '60,'], ['why', 'to', '500,']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom sort key, to convert the last element to an integer just when sorting:

```
sorted(l1, key=lambda l: int(l[2].rstrip(',')))
```

The `key` is used to produce the value on which to sort, for each element in the list. So the `lambda` function is called for each element, and the above code extracts the `l[2]` value, converting it to an integer. The `str.rstrip()` call removes the trailing comma first.

Demo:

```
>>> l1 = [['test', 'hello', '60,'], ['why', 'to', '500,'], ['my', 'choice', '20,']]
>>> sorted(l1, key=lambda l: int(l[2].rstrip(',')))
[['my', 'choice', '20,'], ['test', 'hello', '60,'], ['why', 'to', '500,']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works :)   // one more query, now this sorts the list in ascending order , what to do for descending order sorting ?

Comment: @Zoro99: add `reverse=True` to the `sorted()` call.