# Sorting List of List by inner list's index in Java? (Java Equivalent of Python's 'sorted()')

Tags: java, sorting, compare

In Java, I have a List of List that looks something like  the following:

```
[ ["Kelly", "3.0"], ["Jeff", "2.0"], ["Mark", "1.0]" ]
```

How do I sort the list by a certain index? In this case, index of 1

Ex)

```
Given:   [ ["Kelly", "3.0"], ["Jeff", "2.0"], ["Mark", "1.0"] ]
Desired: [ ["Mark", "1.0"], ["Jeff", "2.0"], ["Kelly", "3.0"] ]
```

What I'm looking for is something very similar to the 'sorted()' method in Python (the exact solution I'm looking for in Python shown here: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-an-index-of-each-inner-list-in-python and here: [sort list of lists by specific index of inner list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227264/sort-list-of-lists-by-specific-index-of-inner-list)) but I'm looking for a solution in Java.

Also as a bonus, how would I sort these in descending order? What about instances of same values (i.e. there's multiple '3.0' values)

Comment: You can use a custom comparator that compares the second element of each list to determine sort order. It's simply a matter of flipping the variables around to achieve descending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java 8 there is method [`List::sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) accepting a custom `Comparator` which can be built using [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-).

So, the input list of lists may be concisely sorted as follows:

```java
List<List<String>> data = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("Kelly", "3.0"),
    Arrays.asList("Mark", "1.0"),
    Arrays.asList("Jeff", "2.0")
);

// sorting by index 1
data.sort(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(1))); 
// [[Mark, 1.0], [Jeff, 2.0], [Kelly, 3.0]]

// sorting by index 1 in reverse order using Collections.reverseOrder
data.sort(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(1), Collections.reverseOrder()));
// [[Kelly, 3.0], [Jeff, 2.0], [Mark, 1.0]]

// sorting by index 0 in reverse order using Comparator.reversed()
// here type of object being compared needs to be specified
data.sort(Comparator.comparing((List<String> x) -> x.get(0)).reversed());
// [[Mark, 1.0], [Kelly, 3.0], [Jeff, 2.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("Jhon", "3.0"), Arrays.asList("Kelly", "3.0"),
    Arrays.asList("Jeff", "2.0"), Arrays.asList("Mark", "1.0"));
//  sort the list by index of 1
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(1)));
System.out.println(list);
//  sort the list by index of 1 descending order
list.sort(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(1))));
System.out.println(list);
```

output:

```
[[Mark, 1.0], [Jeff, 2.0], [Jhon, 3.0], [Kelly, 3.0]]
[[Jhon, 3.0], [Kelly, 3.0], [Jeff, 2.0], [Mark, 1.0]]
```

It is stable sort in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question literally 2 minutes after posting. Always have to love when that happens lol:

```
    for (int i=0; i < listToReverse.size(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < (listToReverse.size()-i-1); j++) {
            if ((int)Double.parseDouble(listToReverse.get(j).get(1)) < (int)Double.parseDouble(listToReverse.get(j+1).get(1))) {
                ArrayList<String> temp = listToReverse.get(j);
                listToReverse.set(j, asList.get(j+1));
                listToReverse.set(j+1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
//This implementation sorts in descending order. Switch the '<' for a '>' to sort in ascending order
```

Thank you to @bliss for also pointing out a custom comparator could be used here. Probably much prettier than the iterative way

Comment: Applying a custom comparator is as simple as `listToReverse.sort((list1, list2) -> list1.get(1).compareTo(list2.get(1)));` and it utilizes a far more efficient library sorting algorithm.